# How do I change multiple rows into single row comma separated value in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

eg:

Problem:

| UserID | typeID |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 3456 |
| 21 | 1234 |
| 21 | 4353 |
| 24 | 5464 |
| 25 | 5356 |

expected output

| UserID | typeID |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 3456,1234,4353 |
| 24 | 5464 |
| 25 | 5356 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) function:

```sql
SELECT UserID, LISTAGG(typeID, ',') AS  typeID
FROM (VALUES
    (21, 3456),
    (21, 1234),
    (21, 4353),
    (24, 5464),
    (25, 5356)) t(UserID, typeID)
GROUP BY UserID;
```